# How to count occurrences of strings in array of arrays?

Tags: javascript

I have the following array of arrays (pasted below) and would like to loop through it to count how many times each color appears. What's the simplest way to go about doing this?

```
[
["Brown"],
["Blue", "Green"],
["Red", "Black", "White", "Other"],
["Green"],
["Green", "Gold"],
["Blue"]
];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) and [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const data = [
  ["Brown"],
  ["Blue", "Green"],
  ["Red", "Black", "White", "Other"],
  ["Green"],
  ["Green", "Gold"],
  ["Blue"]
];

const result = data.flat().reduce((a, v) => (a[v] = (a[v] || 0) + 1, a), {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
const input = [
["Brown"],
["Blue", "Green"],
["Red", "Black", "White", "Other"],
["Green"],
["Green", "Gold"],
["Blue"]
];

const output = input.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  cur.forEach(item => {
    if (!acc[item]) acc[item] = 0;
    acc[item] ++;
  })
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a counter to count and iterate through the array

```
let counter = {}
let colorAry = [
    ["Brown"],
    ["Blue", "Green"],
    ["Red", "Black", "White", "Other"],
    ["Green"],
    ["Green", "Gold"],
    ["Blue"]
];

for(let ary of colorAry) {
    for(let color of ary) {
        if(counter[color]==undefined) counter[color] = 0
        counter[color]++
    }
}
console.log(counter)
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop each array and sub arrays and store the count in another variable.

```js
let data = [
  ["Brown"],
  ["Blue", "Green"],
  ["Red", "Black", "White", "Other"],
  ["Green"],
  ["Green", "Gold"],
  ["Blue"]
];

// to store the count
let counter = {};

// loop each and sub sub arrays
data.forEach(item => {
  item.forEach(subItem => {
    counter[subItem] = counter[subItem] ? counter[subItem] + 1 : 1
  })
});

console.log(counter);
```